# VueJS-like Transitions, Without Vue?

Tags: javascript, css

How do you achieve VueJS-like control over transitions using vanilla JavaScript?

The goal is to make an element have `display: none;` when it's hidden, but maintain the ability to fade it in/out.

I managed to make it fade out by applying a class with an opacity of 0 and then listening for the `transitionend` event to swap the class with a `hide` class that sets `display: none;`. That part actually seems to work well...

However, when trying to do the inverse, it seems to fail. Instead of tranitioning in; it ignores the transition entirely and just appears with full opacity and never fires a `transitionend` event.

```js
const btnShow = document.querySelector('#btnShow');
const btnHide = document.querySelector('#btnHide');
const div = document.querySelector('div');

btnShow.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('btnShow clicked');
  
  div.classList.remove('hide');
  div.classList.add('div-enter');
  div.classList.replace('div-enter', 'div-enter-to');

  div.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    console.log('show transition ended');
    div.classList.remove('div-enter-to');
  }, { once: true });
});

btnHide.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('btnHide clicked');
  
  div.classList.add('div-leave');
  div.classList.replace('div-leave', 'div-leave-to');

  div.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    console.log('hide transition ended');
    div.classList.replace('div-leave-to', 'hide');
  }, { once: true });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.div-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.div-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
}

.div-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.div-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Irrelevant styles */
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  font-size: 100%;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 3rem 0;
  width: 50%;
  background: #4bfa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnShow">show</button>
<button id="btnHide">hide</button>

<div>
  fade out, then set display: none<br />
  then do the reverse...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The hide class should be written like:

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

CSS transitions and animations allow you to animate a specific set of CSS properties. You cannot animate the display property.

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#animatable-properties

Comment: `visibility: hidden;` and `display: none;` have a few differences... One of which is that `display: none;` frees up the space that element was using... which is an aspect I wish to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Use animations instead of transitions , working example of your changed code provided below.

```js
const btnShow = document.querySelector('#btnShow');
const btnHide = document.querySelector('#btnHide');
const div = document.querySelector('div');

btnShow.addEventListener('click', () => {
  div.classList.remove('hide');
  div.classList.add('fade-in');

  div.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    div.classList.remove('fade-in');
  }, { once: true });
});

btnHide.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('btnHide clicked');
  
  div.classList.add('fade-out');

  div.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
    div.classList.replace('fade-out', 'hide');
  }, { once: true });
});
```

```css
@keyframes fade-out {
   0% {opacity: 1;}
   100% {opacity: 0;} 
} 

@keyframes fade-in {
   100% {opacity: 1;}
   0% {opacity: 0;} 
}

.hide { display: none; }
.fade-out {animation-name: fade-out; animation-duration: 1s; }
.fade-in {animation-name: fade-in; animation-duration: 1s; }

/* Irrelevant styles */
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  font-size: 100%;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 3rem 0;
  width: 50%;
  background: #4bfa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnShow">show</button>
<button id="btnHide">hide</button>

<div>
  fade out, then set display: none<br />
  then do the reverse...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks... Unfortunately, that's not what I'm seeking to accomplish. I'm wanting to implement it the VueJS way which doesn't rely on having to use keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by wrapping the enter animations in a `setTimeout(() => {}, 0);`

I don't fully understand why this works, so I'd appreciate comments explaining it. I had tried putting them in a `requestAnimationFrame()` but that didn't seem to have the same effect.

If anyone knows a better or cleaner way to accomplish this, I'd love to see it.

```js
const btnShow = document.querySelector('#btnShow');
const btnHide = document.querySelector('#btnHide');
const div = document.querySelector('div');

btnShow.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('btnShow clicked');
  
  div.classList.replace('hide', 'div-enter');

  setTimeout(() => {
    div.classList.replace('div-enter', 'div-enter-to');
    
    div.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
      console.log('show transition ended');
      div.classList.remove('div-enter-to');
    }, { once: true });
  }, 0);
});

btnHide.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('btnHide clicked');
  
  div.classList.add('div-leave');
  div.classList.replace('div-leave', 'div-leave-to');

  div.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    console.log('hide transition ended');
    div.classList.replace('div-leave-to', 'hide');
  }, { once: true });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.div-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.div-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
}

.div-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.div-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Irrelevant styles */
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  font-size: 100%;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  width: 50%;
  background: #4bfa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  fade out, then set display: none<br />
  then do the reverse...
</div>

<button id="btnShow">show</button>
<button id="btnHide">hide</button>
```